# Proof that this is a Norm

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces

Let $k$ be any natural number. I'd like to prove that the expression
$$
\|f\|_{C^{k}[a, b]}=\max _{0 \leq l \leq k} \max _{a \leq t \leq b}\left|\frac{d^{l} f(t)}{d t^{l}}\right|
$$
is a norm on $C^{k}[a, b]$.

---

What I have accomplished:

For $f \in C^k[a, b]$ we have $0 \leq\|f\|<\infty$.
Positivity: $\|f\| \geq 0$ is obvious and $\|f\|=0$ is equivalent to
$$
\max _{0 \leq l \leq k} \max _{a \leq t \leq b}\left|\frac{d^{l} f(t)}{d t^{l}}\right|=0,
$$
i.e. $f(t)=0$ for all $t \in [a,b]$, i.e. $f=0.$
Absolute homogeneity:
$$
\|\lambda f\|=\max _{0 \leq l \leq k} \max _{a \leq t \leq b}\left|\frac{d^{l} \lambda f(t)}{d t^{l}}\right|=|\lambda| \max _{0 \leq l \leq k} \max _{a \leq t \leq b}\left|\frac{d^{l} f(t)}{d t^{l}}\right|=|\lambda|\|f\| .
$$
Triangle inequality: For each $t \in [a,b]$, the following applies
$$
\left|\frac{d^{l}}{d t^{l}} (f(t)+g(t))\right | \leq\left|\frac{d^{l}}{d t^{l}} f(t)\right |+\left|\frac{d^{l}}{d t^{l}} g(t)\right | \leq\|f\|+\|g\|,
$$
from which follows
$$
\|f+g\|=\max _{0 \leq l \leq k} \max _{a \leq t \leq b}\left|\frac{d^{l}}{d t^{l}} (f(t)+g(t))\right | \leq|f\|+\|g\| . 
$$

I'd like to know if this is flawless or if there is room for enhancement. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, absolutely flawless except for two minor typos in the second and fourth math line.